# Manipulating XML with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I need help manipulating values in an XML file with Python.

The XML looks like this, but with even more plants:

```
<CATALOG>
    <PLANT>
        <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>2.44</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>3</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>9.37</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
    <PLANT>
        <COMMON>Marsh Marigold</COMMON>
        <BOTANICAL>Caltha palustris</BOTANICAL>
        <ZONE>4</ZONE>
        <LIGHT>Mostly Sunny</LIGHT>
        <PRICE>6.81</PRICE>
        <AVAILABILITY>051799</AVAILABILITY>
    </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

I need to be able to change the  value based on the  value.

I have this so far:

```
    if tree.find('.//COMMON').text == 'Bloodroot':
    tree.find('.//PRICE').text = '3.50'
```

This code works, but that's only because it's the first block. If I do this nothing happens:

```
if tree.find('.//COMMON').text == 'Columbine':
    tree.find('.//PRICE').text = '3.50'
```

Can someone point me the right direction here? How do I change the price values for all the plants based on the 'COMMON' value. I've also tried some different things with looping through the xml file with no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation for find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find) says, it stops at the first node it finds. You need to iterate over the parent node to find all of them, and check the value. Here is an example.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

with open("data.xml", "rb") as fo:
    root = ElementTree.parse(fo)

for plantnode in root.findall("PLANT"):
    if plantnode.find("COMMON").text == "Columbine":
        pricenode = plantnode.find("PRICE")
        print(pricenode.text)
        pricenode.text = '3.50'
        print(pricenode.text)
```